# Download cpp binary in android app

Tags: android, c++, compilation

I'm aware that you can download scripts(lua, js) and execute. Is it possible to download C++ compiled code from within android app and link to it?

Answer (score 1):

C++ is a compiled language, specifically compiled for a CPU architecture. There is no way that the JVM which runs an application will let you run a binary specially because this would be a huge security risk, because if you think about it you would be executing foreign code from within the app itself.

Android and even iOS won't let you run code that you just downloaded. Because as I've said you would be opening a huge door towards rogue hackers to run their exploits. For Lua and JavaScript this is different because it can be self-contained withint their interpreters and it would be possible to prevent leaks security-wise.

Comment: While I agree that OP should *NOT* do this, your answer isn't actually true. Java can load native code and access it through JNI. Android has this interface also.

Comment: @ephemient yes you are correct but that native code has to be inside the APK, it can't be simply downloaded and executed.

Comment: It can. Write it to internal storage and `System.loadLibrary()` using the full path.